# Ruby IMAP library: How can I show all messages in a folder?

Tags: ruby, imap

I need a script to fetch all my emails in all my folders and make a local backup of them together with attachments.[here](https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/imap/a-comprehensive-guide-to-interacting-with-imap-using-ruby.html) but it doesn't bring me further with listing all emails belongig to a folder. Also reading the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-2.3.2) doesn't bring me much further.

When I issued

```
imap.list("", "*")
```

And

```
imap.examine("SomeFolder")
```

How can I use this to iterate over all emails of `SomeFolder` ?

And how would I further issue a query to get the messages as well as the associated attachments?

Comment: Frame challenge: there are many imap backup tools already that will download all your messages in .EML form. Is there a reason you need to rewrite this?

Comment: Generally, you'd just want to download the entire MIME segment for every message with the RFC822 fetch item. Write that out to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the UIDs of all emails in a mailbox, use `imap.uid_search(["ALL"])`. You can then fetch them all in [RFC822 (.eml)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) format (which includes their attachments) like this:

```rb
require "net/imap"
require "mail"

# initialize your imap object here
imap = Net::IMAP.new(...)
imap.login(...)

imap.list("", "*").map(&:name).each do |mailbox|
    imap.examine(mailbox)

    # Create directory for mailbox backup
    Dir.mkdir(mailbox) unless Dir.exist? mailbox

    uids = imap.uid_search(["ALL"])
    uids.each_with_index do |uid, i|
        # fetch the email in RFC822 format
        raw_email = imap.uid_fetch(uid, "RFC822").first.attr["RFC822"]

        # use the "mail" gem to parse the raw email and extract some useful info
        email = Mail.new(raw_email)
        puts "[#{i+1}/#{uids.length}] Saving email #{mailbox}/#{uid} (#{email.subject.inspect} from #{email.from.first} at #{email.date})"

        # save the email to a file
        File.write(File.join(mailbox, "#{uid}.eml"), raw_email)
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow thank you SO much for that detailed answer ! This is amazing. Can't upvote enough !

Comment: Do you know / would you explain to me how to fetch Information about attachments and how to get the binary data from the server?

Comment: @vonspotz The attachments are already included in the EML file. You can extract them with the [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem like [this](https://github.com/mikel/mail#testing-and-extracting-attachments).

Comment: @sapphyrus thanks so much for this! Do you know if this will work even for large mailboxes with 10s of thousands of emails? Whats the limit here? When should one implement some sort of batching?