# Ruby IMAP library: How can I upload .eml files to an imap server again?

Tags: ruby, email, imap

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071875/ruby-imap-library-how-can-i-show-all-messages-in-a-folder) thread, I got help with a script to catch all of my emails in their respective folders together with the attachments via the modules `net/imap` and the gem `email`.

I had to change my provider. So now I have the problem of choosing a new email provider and re-upload my emails to that account.

Can you kindly give me advice how to do this with these (or further) modules? Meanwhile, I look through the documentations again myself. I don't want to be spoon fed, it's just that I am not knowledgable with the IMAP RFCs right now, but need the access right now.

If I read a file `mail = Mail.read('path/to/file.eml')`, how would I upload every attribute from the `.eml` file and how would I upload the attachments saved in the same file?

Comment: For instance, if I reupload the .eml to a new mailbox, do I have to generate a new message_id? Or does the server automatically assign a new one? I put it another way: Are there things from the .eml file I can't "recycle" but generate newly?

Comment: If you're looking at the RFC, the command you want is Append.  The Message-ID header comes from the message.  The message sequence number and UID are assigned by the server when it places it in the mailbox.

Comment: More precisely, the MSN will be assigned in order. Append oldest messages first.